# Is there any prior settings while using sqlite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Error is application stopped unexpectedly
and error showing at queueall method at the `Cursor`
When I am executing program then there is an error application stopped unexpectedly.
is there any setting for crating database I android?

```
    public class SQLiteAdapter {

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";
    // Create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);

    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table "
            + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_CONTENT + "text ot null);";

    private SQLiteHelper  sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        context = c;
    }


    // Write to the database
    public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException
    {


        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    // Read from database

    public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException
    {

        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {

        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }


    public long insert(String content)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }
    //Delete data from database
    public int deleteAll() {


        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }



    public String queueAll()

    {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT);

        // moving cursor from 1st to next

        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext())
        {
        result = result + cursor.getString(index_CONTENT)+ "\n";    

        }

        return result;
    }


    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 

    {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            arg0.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Log Cat is:

```
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.example.androidsqlite.SQLiteAdapter.queueAll(SQLiteAdapter.java:80)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.example.androidsqlite.AndroidSQLite.onCreate(AndroidSQLite.java:35)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-23 23:30:29.819: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where is your db helper class? Base on your code sqLiteDatabase didn't opened get database. That probably the problem.

Comment: show all your relevant code connected to sqlite. It will help us to find the issue.

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace. The exception name is missing